# Choose first comma after specific pattern on each line

Tags: regex, sublime-text-2

I have almost thousand lines each with the same structure and I have to edit one part of it.

```
"650","4","The lenght of this part varies, Here's some commas, here, and, there"
"203","4","Now this is shorter, Don't edit these commas, here"
"102","4","Really short, More commas, incoming"
```

The above should be edited to this ie add the apostrophes.

```
"650","4","The lenght of this part varies", "Here's some commas, here, and, there"
"203","4","Now this is shorter", "Don't edit these commas, here"
"102","4","Really short", "More commas, incoming"
```

How do I choose the first comma after **"4","**? I'm using Sublime Text 2 and it supports regular expressions.

It's been so many years since I last needed regular expressions so be gentle. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should match the part right befor the comma `","[._[:alnum:]-0-9]+"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Sublime Text to do a find and replace with a regex, but this works in Notepad++, and so hopefully you can find a way to use it.

```
(.{5},.{3}?,.*?),
```

That will capture the first portion, up to the 3rd comma, then for your replacement you can do:

```
\1", "
```

And that will insert the first portion back into the original string, and then replace the comma with `", "`.

Comment: This assumes that every one of the first two number fields are exactly 3 digit and 1 digits long. Might be safer to do `"\d+"`? I guess it depends on the data file and the OP said "same structure" so maybe that means there is never a "99" in column 1...

Comment: @beroe, you're absolutely right, but I think in  this case, the hard part probably isn't the regular expression, but instead creating and using a capture group in a find/replace. If anyone in the future comes across this problem, you can use http://rubular.com/ to try out other regular expressions for a differently formatted text file.